# How to code a new Windows Shell?

Tags: c++, windows-vista, windows-shell

How would I go about coding a new Windows Vista Shell?

Comment: Do you mean an Explorer replacement or a command shell (like PowerShell or bash)?

Comment: Explorer
 Always use GUI now barely use cmd

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Everything you need to do as shell has never been documented, so there are some issues with file change notifications etc. The basics are:

1. SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMINIMIZEDMETRICS,...MINIMIZEDMETRICS) with (undocumented?) flag 8
2. Register as the shell (SetShellWindow,SetProgmanWindow,ShellDDEInit,RegisterShellHook etc)
3. Hide welcome screen by setting a signal ("msgina: ShellReadyEvent" and "ShellDesktopSwitchEvent")
4. Start registry run key, start menu\startup and ShellServiceObjects
5. Set registry Explorer\SessionInfo

The good thing is, you are not the first to write a new shell, if you look around, you can find some obscure required info. Here is a list to get you started:

- https://web.archive.org/web/2019/http://www.lsdev.org/doku.php
- http://bb4win.cvs.sourceforge.net/bb4win/blackbox/Blackbox.cpp?revision=1.49&view=markup
- http://xoblite.net/source/Blackbox.cpp.html
- http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/trunk/reactos/base/shell/
- http://www.geoffchappell.com/viewer.htm?doc=studies/windows/shell/explorer/index.htm&tx=36

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start would be investigating how to build a command line parser, something that can tokenize and interpret the inputs.  There are tools that can help with this like [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/), or you might like to try building your own.

Once you've parsed the inputs you need to decide what actions to take - launching processes, piping between processes, redirecting output - and making those system calls.

If you're just after a more powerful shell rather than interested in building one, give [PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx) a try.