# Check if windows shell has finished loading startup programs

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How can i programatically check if the windows shell (explorer) has loaded all startup programs & the user login process is over ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a somewhat documented event you can wait for, but it is signaled when explorer has *started* loading. On XP this event is called "msgina: ShellReadyEvent" and "ShellDesktopSwitchEvent" on Vista. I linked to the sources of some alternative shells in a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270527/how-to-code-a-new-windows-shell/2283599#2283599) related to this event.

Another alternative would be to listen for the [Taskbar Creation Notification message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144179(VS.85).aspx#Taskbar_Creation_Not). It can fire more than once so you would need to keep track of that.

On Vista+ there is one last alternative that **might** just work: Programs set to run at startup are part of a job object so they cannot run at high priority. If your program runs at startup you could maybe check for this, either by using IsProcessInJob or SetPriorityClass+GetPriorityClass in a loop. (SetPriorityClass will lie about its return value IIRC)